# array is not working from database in asp.net mvc and alpine.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, alpine.js

here is my data from database

```
 function handleClick(event, ProductId) 
   {
 

    fetch(`/Home/ProductDesc?ProductId=${ProductId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
           
           // Alpine.store('ProductName', data.productName);
           Alpine.store('ProductId',data.productName);
            Alpine.store('Variants', data.variant);
            console.log(Alpine.store('Variants'));
       
           
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
      
   }
```

notice variants

[image]

this is my razor view

```
   <div x-data="{ variants: Alpine.store('Variants') }">
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <template x-for="(variant, index) in variants" :key="index">
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <p>Variant Name: <span x-text="variant.variantName"></span></p>
                                                                            <p>Variant Value: <span x-text="variant.variantValue"></span></p>
                                                                            <p>Product Image: <span x-text="variant.productImage"></span></p>
                                                                            <p>Price: <span x-text="variant.price"></span></p>
                                                                            <p>Special Price: <span x-text="variant.specialPrice"></span></p>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </template>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
```

but it is not displaying anything what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is `x-data="{ variants: Alpine.store('Variants') }"` part, because it's not reactive. You put the value of `Alpine.store('Variants')` at the component initialization phase to the local variable `variants`. But at that point `Alpine.store('Variants')` is `undefined`, since you only create that store later in `handleClick()` function.

To solve the problem, remove the `variants` local variable and use the [`$store` global object](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) directly in the template:

```
<template x-for="(variant, index) in $store.Variants" :key="index">
```

Alternatively you can initialize separately the store object with an empty array (in an `alpine:init` event listener block), so `variants` local variable becomes reactive.